# Python/BeautifulSoup - how to remove all tags from an element?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I simply strip all tags from an element I find in BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 146):

With `BeautifulStoneSoup` gone in `bs4`, it's even simpler in Python3

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

Comment: It is better to use `get_text()` instead of `getText()`.

Comment: Why is that? It may well be the case, but it'd be helpful to understand why.

Comment: getText() is bs3 syntax and not pep8 compliant. It will likely be deprecated.

Comment: somebody needs to make this the accepted answer! other solutions are great, but this one is the way to do it. no need to invent the wheel twice.

Answer (score 18):

why has no answer I've seen mentioned anything about the `unwrap` method? Or, even easier, the `get_text` method

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Answer (score 16):

Use [get_text()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text), it returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string.

For instance, remove all different script tags from the following text:

```
<td><a href="http://www.irit.fr/SC">Signal et Communication</a>
<br/><a href="http://www.irit.fr/IRT">Ingénierie Réseaux et Télécommunications</a>
</td>
```

The expected result is:

```
Signal et Communication
Ingénierie Réseaux et Télécommunications
```

Here is the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

text = '''
<td><a href="http://www.irit.fr/SC">Signal et Communication</a>
<br/><a href="http://www.irit.fr/IRT">Ingénierie Réseaux et Télécommunications</a>
</td>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

print(soup.get_text())
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the decompose method in bs4:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<body><a href="http://example.com/">I linked to <i>example.com</i></a></body>')

for a in soup.find('a').children:
    if isinstance(a,bs4.element.Tag):
        a.decompose()

print soup

Out: <html><body><a href="http://example.com/">I linked to </a></body></html>
```

Answer (score 6):

Code to simply get the contents as text instead of html:

`html_text` parameter is the string which you will pass in this function to get the text

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like this is the way to do! as simple as that

with this line you are joining together the all text parts within the current element

```
''.join(htmlelement.find(text=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the source code: you can get the text which is exactly in the URL

```
URL = ''
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser').get_text()
print(soup)
```