# How to Parse HTML in Robot Framework

Tags: python, html, parsing, robotframework

Below is my text and it store in the `${Tooltipdata}`:

```
    <hr><b><strong>Task Details</strong></b><hr><b>Date Created: </b> 02/21/2014 07:52pm<br> 
<b>Date Modified: </b> 02/24/2014 05:47pm<br><b>Assigned to: </b> Administrator<br>
<b>Created By: </b> Administrator<br><b>Status: </b> Pending Input<br><b>Description:
 </b> test<br>
```

I want to result as like this:

```
Task Details  Date Created:  02/21/2014 07:52pm    Date Modified:  02/24/2014 05:47pm    Assigned to:  Administrator   
 Created By:  Administrator   
 Status:  Pending Input   
 Description:  test.
```

Simple I want to remove HTML tag.

Comment: how to remove HTML tag in Robot Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.4#Evaluate) keyword to run the python [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) command. Something like this should work:

```
*** Keywords ***
| Remove HTML tags
| | [Documentation] | Strip HTML tags from the given string
| | [Arguments]     | ${string}
| | ${result}=      | Evaluate | re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', '''${string}''') | re
| | [Return]        | ${result}

*** Test cases ***
| Example
| | ${Tooltipdata}= | Some keyword which returns the tooltip data
| | ${string}= | Remove HTML tags | ${Tooltipdata}
```

If you're not familiar with regular expressions, the above expression means "match the shortest string that is between < and >', and the `re.sub` command will replace each occurrence with the empty string.

This will fail if your html tags include attributes that have `>` in them, and it will also replace non-html tags if your data includes both < and >, but that's the risk you take when you try to parse HTML with regular expressions. In your specific example, you should be safe.

The better alternative is to write a keyword in python, and use a real HTML parsing library such as [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the data. For a code example, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element).

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a regex :

```
import re

data = "<hr><b><strong>Task Details</strong></b><hr><b>Date Created: </b> 02/21/2014 7:52pm<br><b>Date Modified: </b> 02/24/2014 05:47pm<br><b>Assigned to: </b> Administrator<br><b>Created By: </b> Administrator<br><b>Status: </b> Pending Input<br><b>Description: </b> test<br>"
# get text without tag
result = re.split(r'<[A-z\/]*>', data)

# print with removed tag
print ''.join(result)
```

Comment: what is re and How to import re in robot framework please explain it??

Comment: re is for regex in python see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html, regarding how to import re in robot framework put `import re` in your python code

Comment: You mean i need to create library for this?

Comment: to prevent misunderstanding, it would be helpful if you provide the rest of your code. as i understand, this is what you want as stated "I want to remove HTML tag.", the code will do exactly that.

Comment: I am getting tool tip and store in the ${ToolTipdata}, its work fine but shows with html tag. this is code : ${Tooltipdata}    Execute JavaScript    var el = document.evaluate("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span", document, null, 9, null).singleNodeValue; return $(el).data('tooltip').options.title;
 
Log    ${Tooltipdata}

Comment: could you add those code in your question (use the edit question and add your new code)? read code in the comment section is hard. i'll look at it

Answer (score 0):

By using String Library we can Replace the String.  this is code which i use for Replace String.

```
${str} =    Replace String    ${Tooltipdata}    <hr>    a
```