# Python and BeautifulSoup URL parse

Tags: python

I have the following code which i am using to try and get the title and description from the redsox news. I have it working but for one minor detail.  its showing the tags.  How can i eliminate them?

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
# or if you're using BeautifulSoup4:
# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://partner.mlb.com/partnerxml/gen/news/rss/bos.xml').read())

title = soup.find('item').title
desc = soup.find('item').description

print "Title: %s " % (title)
print "Summary: %s " % (desc)
```

This is what it shows

```
Title: <title>Shaw or Panda? Hot corner duel heats up</title> 
Summary: <description>With two weeks until Opening Day, the hottest topic in Red Sox camp is the competition at the hot corner between incumbent Pablo Sandoval and the emerging Travis Shaw.</description> 
>>>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element

Comment: Might want to read the docs http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
print "Title: %s " % (title.text)
print "Summary: %s " % (desc.text)
```

You can do better with BeautifulSoup, but this is the quick way to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for that short but sweet answer

Answer (score -1):

```
print ("Title: %s " % (title.get_text()))
print ("Summary: %s " % (desc.get_text()))
```

this works