# How to get text within HTML Tags?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div class=" col-md-8">
  <strong>3.</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;For 
  <i>ax</i>
  <sup>2</sup> + <i>bx</i> + <i>c</i> = 0, 
  which of the following statement is wrong?
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class=" col-md-6">
     (a) three zeros
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-6">
     (b) one zero
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-6">
     (c) two zeros
  </div>
  <div class=" col-md-6">
     (d) none of these
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code repeats for Every question and answer.I am using BeautifulSoup to retrieve data but didn't succeed.

Can anyone help me how to retrieve data(only text and no html tags) using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element?

Comment: No the link you provided is not the right solution to my problem

Comment: Can you please provide an example solution?

Comment: 3. Every quadratic polynomial can have at most

 (a) three zeros      (b) one zero        
(c) two zero         (d) none of these

Comment: @john and where do you get the "Every quadratic polynomial can have at most" part?

Comment: In code above within the <strong>Every quadratic polynomial can have at most</strong> tag

Comment: @john that is not in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

** note, I edited the markup to include what you specified **

I just compiled some code and I can confirm that this outputs the correct string. See the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

string = """<div class=" col-md-8">
<strong></strong>Every quadratic polynomial can have at most 
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class=" col-md-6">
(a) three zeros
</div>
<div class=" col-md-6">
(b) one zero
</div>
<div class=" col-md-6">
(c) two zeros
</div>
<div class=" col-md-6">
(d) none of these
</div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(string, "html.parser")
text = soup.get_text().replace("\n", "")

print(text)
```

This will output

`Every quadratic polynomial can have at most (a) three zeros(b) one zero(c) two zeros(d) none of these`

I am not sure of the *exact* format you are wanting, so tweaking yourself will have to be done.