# How to Clean tags from html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to train data using the NLTK library. I follow a step-by-step process. I did the first step, but while doing the second step I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

I tried my best to rectify it but I'm getting the same error again.

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://php.net/') 
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
print (text)
```

this is my error

```
C:\python\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 8 of the file E:/secure secure/chatbot-master/nltk.py. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP})

to this:

 BeautifulSoup(YOUR_MARKUP, "html5lib")

  markup_type=markup_type))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/secure secure/chatbot-master/nltk.py", line 8, in <module>
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 228, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 289, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_html5lib.py", line 72, in feed
    doc = parser.parse(markup, **extra_kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 236, in parse
    parseMeta=parseMeta, useChardet=useChardet)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 89, in _parse
    parser=self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\html5lib\tokenizer.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.stream = HTMLInputStream(stream, encoding, parseMeta, useChardet)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\html5lib\inputstream.py", line 148, in HTMLInputStream
    return HTMLBinaryInputStream(source, encoding, parseMeta, chardet)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\html5lib\inputstream.py", line 416, in __init__
    self.rawStream = self.openStream(source)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\html5lib\inputstream.py", line 453, in openStream
    stream = BytesIO(source)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

Comment: Have you looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element ? you can try get_text: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Comment: I tried running your script and it returns the text just fine? Can you post the detailed error message?

Comment: While running im getting error like this

Comment: TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'

Comment: script is working fine, please edit the question and add the error message as well.

Comment: i'm trying to paste full error but its not posting @sid2491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer that works in python 3

```
invalidTags = ['br','b','font']
def stripTags(html, invalid_tags):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in invalid_tags:
            s = "::"
            for c in tag.contents:
                if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                    c = stripTags(str(c), invalid_tags)
                s += str(c)
            tag.replaceWith(s)
    return soup
```

Comment: Hm. What am I missing? `NameError: name 'NavigableString' is not defined`

Comment: Fore some reason, I had to add `from bs4 import NavigableString`. Works now!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by implementing a simple tag-stripper.

```
def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in invalid_tags:
            s = ""
            for c in tag.contents:
                if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                    c = strip_tags(unicode(c), invalid_tags)
                s += unicode(c)
            tag.replaceWith(s)
    return soup

html = "<p>Love, <b>Hate</b>, and <i>Hap<b>piness</b><u>y</u></i></p>"
invalid_tags = ['b', 'i', 'u']
print strip_tags(html, invalid_tags)
```

The result is:

```
<p>Love, Hate, and Happiness</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as is.

The `UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified` was when your statement was `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)`.

The `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'` error might be due to an issue with dependencies.

The [bs4 documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) says if you do not specify a parser, like `BeautifulSoup(markup)`, it uses the best HTML parser that is installed on your system:

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

On my system, using `BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")` worked just fine, with decent speed, without any warnings. `html.parser` comes with Python’s standard library.

The documentation also [summarizes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) the advantages and disadvantages of each parser library:

[image]

Try `BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")`. It should work.

If you want speed, you could try `BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")`.  If you do not have lxml’s HTML parser, on Windows you may want to install it with `pip install lxml`.