# How to remove surplus tags from beautiful soup result

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to get only the content in <p> tag and remove the surplus div tags. 
My code is:

```
page = """
<p style="text-align: justify">content that I want
    <div ><!-- /316485075/agk_116000_pos_3_sidebar_mobile -->
        <div id="agk_116000_pos_3_sidebar_mobile">
            <script>
                script code
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="nopadding clearfix hidden-print">
            <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
            <!-- /316485075/agk_116000_pos_4_conteudo_desktop -->
                <div id="agk_116000_pos_4_conteudo_desktop" style="height:90px; width:728px;">
                    <script>
                        script code
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
p = soup.find_all('p', {'style' : 'text-align: justify'})
```

And I just want to get the string `<p>content that I want</p>` and remove all the divs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python/BeautifulSoup - how to remove all tags from an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element)

Comment: I don't wanna strip the tags, I want to remove the tags that is not relevant for my application

Comment: Capture group 2 contains your content `<(.*?)(?:\s.+?>)(.*?)</\1[>]?`
See https://regex101.com/r/m8DQic/1

Comment: @nnamdi no don't do that.

Comment: what do you mean @ctwheeels?

Comment: What I mean is don't use regex on XML or HTML. It **WILL** break.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`replace_with()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) function to remove the tags along with its contents.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')   # html is HTML you've provided in question
soup.find('div').replace_with('')
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<p style="text-align: justify">content that I want

</p>
```

Note: I'm using `soup.find('div')` here as all the unwanted tags are inside the first `div` tag. Hence, if you remove that tag, all others will get removed. But, if you want to remove all the tags other than the `p` tags in a HTML where the format is not like this, you'll have to use this:

```
for tag in soup.find_all():
    if tag.name == 'p':
        continue
    tag.replace_with('')
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
[tag.replace_with('') for tag in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name != 'p')]
```

---

If you simply want the `content that I want` text, you can use this:

```
print(soup.find('p').contents[0])
# content that I want
```

Comment: But what if I have a <b> tag inside the <p> or <i> tag, it will only return the string before these tags (<b> or <i>)

Comment: Your statement is a bit vague. Can you add such example in the question along with the expected output?

Answer (score -1):

Capture group 2 contains your content `<(.*?)(?:\s.+?>)(.*?)</\1[>]?`

See https://regex101.com/r/m8DQic/1