# Extract text from HTML Tags and plain text (not wrapped in tags)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<p class="qotCJE">
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/to+pay" title="to payの意味" class="crosslink">to pay</a> 
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/charges" title="chargesの意味" class="crosslink">charges</a> 
from one's 
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/bank+account" title="bank accountの意味" class="crosslink">bank account</a>
</p>
```

I am trying to reconstruct the sentence "to pay charges from one's bank account" that's split into the above HTML code. My problem is that one part of the sentence is not wrapped inside HTML tags. When I try to use:

```
BeautifulSoup.find_all()
```

I only get the text between the link tags and when I try to use

```
BeautifulSoup.contents
```

I only get "from one's" but not the text in between the link tags.

Is there a way to go through this code and reconstruct the sentence?

**Edit:**
The above code is just an example, I am trying to scrape a dictionary so the order of the strings and which parts will be inside/outside tags will be arbitrary.

Comment: Try `soup.text`.

Comment: you could try to use the "get_text()" function as stated there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element

Comment: @Luc this doesn't give me the desired result, when I use get_text() I do get all the text inside the tags, but I am still missing the part that is not inside the <a> tags

Comment: You need to apply `.text` or `get_text()` to the `<p>` tag, not the `<a>`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<p class="qotCJE">
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/to+pay" title="to payの意味" class="crosslink">to pay</a>
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/charges" title="chargesの意味" class="crosslink">charges</a>
from one's
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/bank+account" title="bank accountの意味" class="crosslink">bank account</a>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print(soup.text)
# to pay
# charges
# from one's
# bank account

print(soup.text.replace('\n', ' '))
# to pay charges from one's bank account
```

Comment: Oh ok that's what I was looking for, seems like I just got confused as to where I was in the tree. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
After digging into the dictionary website a bit, I came up with the following solution. Under a each `<p>` tag of a sentence, we could do the following:

```
from bs4.element import Tag
from bs4.element import NavigableString


res = []

for segment in p.contents:
    if isinstance(segment, NavigableString):
        res.append(segment)
    elif isinstance(segment, Tag):
        res.append(segment.text)

final_sentence = ''.join(res[:-2])
```

Hope it helps

---

If you just want to extract text from `title` attribute, you could do

```
# assuming text is the html text given above
soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'html5lib')
a_tags = soup.select('a')
a_strs = (a['title'] for a in a_tags)
final_sentence = "{} {} from one's {}".format(a_strs)
```

Comment: Right, but I am trying to do this for a generic response (I am scraping a web dictionary), so the method of inserting a static string won't work for me. Maybe I should clarify that in my post

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to achieve the same:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<p class="qotCJE">
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/to+pay" title="to payの意味" class="crosslink">to pay</a>
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/charges" title="chargesの意味" class="crosslink">charges</a>
from one's
<a href="https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/bank+account" title="bank accountの意味" class="crosslink">bank account</a>
</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
print(soup.get_text(" ",strip=True))
```

Output:

```
to pay charges from one's bank account
```