# Convert html with tags into spaCy traning data

Tags: python, html, spacy

I want to convert some HTML text to the spaCy NER training dataset. The entities I want to label are marked by the `<strong>` tag in the html. For example, Uber as an `ORG` is in the tag `<strong>`

```
<strong>Uber</strong> blew through $1 million
```

I want to convert this text into an acceptable format for training spaCy.

```
train_data = [("Uber blew through $1 million", {"entities": [(0, 4, "ORG")]})]
```

Is there a convenient way to do so in python?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use BeautifulSoup to preprocess the text, as described here:

[Python/BeautifulSoup - how to remove all tags from an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element)