# regex for loop over list in python

Tags: python, html, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I **have** this list

```
[<th align="left">
 <a href="blablabla">F</a>ojweousa</th>,
 <th align="left">
 <a href="blablabla">S</a>awdefrgt</th>, ...]
```

and **want**

1. the one single character after `">`
2. the multiple characters between `</a>` and `</th>,`

to be concatenated so that i can move on with my life.

Here is my **code**

```
item2 = []
for element in items2:
    first_letter = re.search('">.</a', str(items2))
    second_letter = re.search(r'</a>[a-zA-Z0-9]</th>,', str(items2))
    item2.append([str(first_letter) + str(second_letter)])
```

I know i should do something like `item2.group` or `item2.join` but if i do, the **output** gets even more messy. Here is the output with the current code

```
[['<re.Match object; span=(155, 161), match=\'">F</a\'>None'],
 ['<re.Match object; span=(155, 161), match=\'">F</a\'>None'],
 ...]]
```

I would **like** the output to look like this so that i can use it in pd.dataframe:

```
[Fojweousa, Sawdefrgt, ...]
```

It is a list, that is why i cant use html bs4 or select methods.

Comment: *"It is a list, that is why i cant use html bs4 or select methods."* - Where did this list come from? Was bs4 used to create it?

Comment: Try `item2 = [re.sub(r'<[^>]*>', '', x).strip() for x in items2]`. But using BeautifulSoup would be the best solution, where you may strip tags [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206380/python-beautifulsoup-how-to-remove-all-tags-from-an-element).

Comment: @Tomalak Yes. @Wiktor TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object. Here is the bs4 call: `items2 = table.find_all('th', attrs={'align': 'left'})[1:]`     I cannot combine two bs4 methods like `get_text()` and `find_all()`   Every time i do one `find_all()` i get lists and afterwards need to rely on regex. Which is annoying

Comment: Do it like `result = [x.get_text() for x in table.find_all('th', attrs={'align': 'left'})[1:]]`

Comment: @id345678 If you have used bs4 to create this list, you can use bs4 to extract the text you want. You don't ever want to use regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that one worked. Except that every string has a `\n` before its first character. I really need to think your code through. Finally i found a way to do more than 1 bs4 method. YEsssssss

Comment: d345678 thanks for this awesome regex-example. This is so great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the BeautifulSoup [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to get plain text from each element you found with `find_all` *and* `strip` to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace:

```
items2 = table.find_all('th', attrs={'align': 'left'})[1:]
result = [x.get_text().strip() for x in items2]
```

Here, `.find_all('th', attrs={'align': 'left'})` finds all `th` elements with attribute `align` equal to `left`, and `[1:]` skips the first occurrence.

Next, `[x.get_text().strip() for x in items2]` is a list comprehension that iterates over the found items (`items2`, `x` is each single found element) and gets plain text from each `x` element using `x.get_text()` and `strip()` removes leading/trailing whitespace.