# How to get text from nested html table with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

Within each of the main tables respectively, there are two tables nested of which the first one contains the data A_A_A_A that i want to extract to a pandas.dataframe

```
<table>
<tr valign="top">
   <td> </td>
   <td>
      <br/>
      <center>
         <h2>asd</h2>
      </center>
      <h4>asd</h4>
      <table>
         <tr>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabcol" width="100%">
         <tr>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="3%"> </td>
            <td>
               <table border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                     <td width="2%"> </td>
                     <td> A_A_A_A <br/> A_A_A_A <a href="http://url.com" target="new">111</a>-222<br/> </td>
                     <td width="2%"> </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td width="3%"> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td width="3%"> </td>
            <td>
               <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                     <td width="4%"> </td>
                     <td class="unique"> asd <br/> asd </td>
                     <td width="4%"> </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </td>
            <td width="3%"> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td> </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tabcol" width="100%">
      . 
      .
      .
      </table>
      <br/>
      <table>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I figured that because of the limited availiability of attributes the only way to go forward would be an iteration over a `td` siblings with `.next_siblings` and if needed `.next_elements`

```
data1 = []
for item in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'width': '2%'}):
    data = item.find_next_sibling().text
    data1.append(data)
```

returns and empty list []. Now i dont know forward because i cannot identify any other helpful attributes/classes that would help me get to the middle `td` that contains the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .find_next(name=None, attrs={}, text=None, **kwargs)

Returns the first item that matches the given criteria and appears after this Tag in the document. So in your case:

```
item = soup.find('td', attrs={'width': '2%'})
data = item.find_next('td').text
```

Note that, I removed `for` loop since the desired data is coming after first `td` with `width: '2%'`. After running this, `data` will be:

```
' A_A_A_A  A_A_A_A 111-222 '
```

Answer (score 1):

I took @Wiktor Stribiżew answer from here [regex for loop over list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66152180/regex-for-loop-over-list-in-python)
and kind of merged it with yours @Rustam Garayev

```
item = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'width': '2%'})
data = [x.find_next('td').text for x in item]
```

since i **needed not only the first AAAA but from all the following tables** as well. The code above gives this output:

```
['A_A_A_A',
 '\xa0',
 'A_A_A_A',
 '\xa0', ...]
```

which is good enough for my purpose. I think the `'\xa0'` comes from it trying to do the `find_next` on the third `td` sibling, which does not have a consecutive.